# В какой момент лучше начинать адаптировать страницу

Tags: html, css

Есть макет, начинаю верстку, когда лучше начинать адаптировать к разным экранам, после того как страница сверстана целиком или когда готов блок, например `хедер`, `футер`?

Comment: Не возможно дать объективный ответ... Все зависит от твоих навыков... Кому как легче..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это дело вкуса, так что правильного ответа нет.

Как делаю я:

Во время верстки каждого элемента стараюсь предусмотреть его адаптивность сразу, но по окончании основной версии, когда уже видна картина целиком, начинаю отлаживать адаптивность во взаимодействии со всеми элементами.

Comment: Я делаю адаптивность по секциям :-) Сверстал секцию - адаптировал и дальше, но первом этапе адаптивность делаю примерной, главное чтоб боле менее ровно всё выглядело, после полной верстки уже правлю косяки :-) но тут ХЗ всё таки кому как удобно мне кажется